# page width increased after clicking noCAPTCHA checkbox (with bootstrap-rtl)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, recaptcha

I'm using [Bootstrap-rtl](https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl) and my page contains sticky header & footer (as in [bootstrap's example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/)).

I've noticed that when I run the page on small screen (width less than ~760px).
and than click the "I'm not a robot" button, the header expends to the large view, and the page width grows unexpectedly.

I've noticed that removing the "position : relative" from the html tag, fixes the issue, but breaks the sticky footer.
unfortunately I couldn't find any other solution of sticky footer that works well with the fixed header.

I uploaded [a simple example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3706586/test.html), to reproduce the issue

Any idea will be appreciated,
Thanks!

Meir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the parent div of `.gc-bubbleDefault.pls-container` and hide it

```
$(".gc-bubbleDefault.pls-container").parent().css("display", "none");
```

Please try above code or

if($(".gc-bubbleDefault.pls-container").parent().css("width")=="106px")
{$(".gc-bubbleDefault.pls-container").parent().css("display", "none");}

Comment: apparently, the problem is with the direction of the page, since the noCAPTCHA sets the left value to -10000px, which cases the problem with html position relative.

Comment: yes you are right, but we can control that by css
body{overflow-x:hidden;}